# How to remove focus from a layout?

Tags: android, android-standout

Im trying to make a task manager application. When the user swipes right a transparent bar will show displaying the background running apps. When the user swipes left, the transparent bar will be hidden. I got the swipes to work and the transparent bar to show up on the screen correctly with the corresponding swipe, however i ran into a problem. When the user swipes left the transparent bar is hidden, however the layout seems to still be in focus. I tried to set the focus to false but that didnt work. Initially, if the transparent bar was over an application, when the user swipes left to hide the bar, he wouldnt be able to click the application. How do i remove the focus from the bar and make it so that anything thats underneath the bar can be clickable?

Using: Standout Library
Code:

```
package wei.mark.example;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import wei.mark.standout.StandOutWindow;
import wei.mark.standout.constants.StandOutFlags;
import wei.mark.standout.ui.Window;

public class SimpleWindow extends StandOutWindow {
private View touchView, mainPanel;

@Override
public String getAppName() {
    return "SimpleWindow";
}

@Override
public int getAppIcon() {
    return android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel;
}

@Override
public void createAndAttachView(int id, FrameLayout frame) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple, frame, true);
    touchView = frame.findViewById(R.id.touchView);
    mainPanel = frame.findViewById(R.id.mainPanel);
    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mainPanel.getLayoutParams();


    touchView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this){
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            mainPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            mainPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });


}

// Set Left Most
@Override
public StandOutLayoutParams getParams(int id, Window window) {
    return new StandOutLayoutParams(id, 300, 1920,
            StandOutLayoutParams.LEFT, StandOutLayoutParams.LEFT);
}

// move the window by dragging the view
@Override
public int getFlags(int id) {
    return super.getFlags(id)
            | StandOutFlags.FLAG_WINDOW_FOCUSABLE_DISABLE;
}

@Override
public String getPersistentNotificationMessage(int id) {
    return "Shiftr";
}

@Override
public Intent getPersistentNotificationIntent(int id) {
    return StandOutWindow.getCloseIntent(this, SimpleWindow.class, id);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In the StandoutWindow.java, change:

```
    TYPE_PHONE
```

to

```
    TYPY_SYSTEM_OVERLAY
```

But this will make all the windows non-touchable. If you can modify the library so that when you change the type of window you want by swiping somehow you change window type. Or change window xpos and ypos offscreen and update window using 
     window.setLayoutParams .